# want to insert the array of order_ids as separate one by one inserts in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, opencart, opencart2.x

I want to **insert the array of order_ids** as **separate one by one inserts** in **mysql db** on php like i had order_ids variable as

```
$order_ids = (123,223,354,343,566,334);
```

**want to insert in a db column as separate insert like**

```
INSERT INTO `oc_delivery`( `order_id`, `agent_name`) VALUES ('123', 'samm');
INSERT INTO `oc_delivery`( `order_id`, `agent_name`) VALUES ('223', 'samm');
```

how can i achieve this.. help me friends. thanks in advance

Comment: how about a loop?

Comment: im a beginner how to do that.? @Arvind

Comment: why cant you use a loop ? and agent_name is same for every order id ?

Comment: At one session agent_name is same for every order_id.  after insert page refreshed to start new session and user may select different agent on form. @JithinScaria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code to insert array of `order_ids` in `mysql`. So, you can achieve it with only one db query.

```
<?php  
    $order_ids = array(123,223,354,343,566,334);
    $query = 'INSERT INTO oc_delivery(order_id,agent_name) VALUES ';

    for ($i=0; $i < count($order_ids); $i++)
    { 
         $query .= '('.$order_ids[$i].',"samm")';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 foreach($order_ids as $value)
 {$sql="INSERT INTO `oc_delivery`( `order_id`, `agent_name`) VALUES ('$value', 'samm')";
 mysqli_query(connection_object,$sql);}
```

Comment: @sabhi You haven't executed the query. Refer my answer.

Comment: It will fires new query every time. In this case your query executes 6 times. You should try with single query

Answer (score 1):

```
   for($i=0;$i<count($order_ids);$i++){
INSERT INTO `oc_delivery`( `order_id`, `agent_name`) VALUES ($order_ids[$i], 'name1');
}
```

Comment: It will fires new query every time. In this case your query executes 6 times. You should try with single query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
foreach ($order_ids as $order_id) {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO oc_delivery( "order_id", "agent_name") VALUES ($order_id, "samm")';   
}
```

Comment: It will fires new query every time. In this case your query executes 6 times. You should try with single query